# How do I line up a table and a bar chart using Rmarkdown/knitr?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to have a table automatically created in Rmarkdown, and also a bar chart. I would like the bars of the bar chart to line up with the rows of the table. How can I do this? Also I'd like the table to be pretty, too.

Comment: It would help if you gave an example. For instance, you could show reproducible code for a table and a bar chart that *don't* align, and ask how they align. Otherwise, you're forcing answerers to make up example data for you, besides which there are mysteries about what you're doing. (How many columns are in your table/plot? Do you want to use ggplot2 or base plotting for the bar chart? Does your table have wide text in it?)

Comment: What about using [sparkline](https://github.com/htmlwidgets/sparkline) or the [formattable](http://renkun.me/formattable/) packages to have the charts inside of the table (to make sure alignment is right)?